# How to determine command line options from ansible playbook

Tags: ansible

I need to determine if someone as used `--ask-vault-pass` option while executing their playbook or not. If they have not issued the `ansible-playbook` command with `--ask-vault-pass`, fail it.

Pass if someone run like:

```
ansible-playbook -i myinv.ini test.yml --ask-vault-pass
```

Fail if someone run like:

```
ansible-playbook -i myinv.ini test.yml
```

Note that, this is not `extra-vars` which I could validate.

Comment: Why do you want to monitor it, your playbook will fail itself with error: `ERROR! Attempting to decrypt but no vault secrets found` if the password is not provided and it tries to decrypt it

Comment: I am using vault pass at very late stage of execution, I want to fail at the start if user misses it.

Comment: It will fail immediately at the start if it needs vault anywhere in the playbook.

Comment: no sir, its failing for me at very late stage. Also, I need to give user proper message that they have missed adding `--ask-vault-pass`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is not detecting the `--ask-vaul-pass` option but will still achieve your requirement. Note anyway that detecting this option in itself is not sufficient for your need since you can provide the vault password in different ways (`--vault-passwork-file` option, environment variables...)

Basically, I'm testing one of the vars that I know is encoded and failing the playbook nicely if we cannot decode. I targeted localhost for the purpose of the test but you can target any group. This is why I used `run_once` on the test task to make sure we only test once for all hosts in the play. I also used `no_log` to make sure we don't leak any sensitive data on screen.

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    test_var: !vault |
      $ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256
      <encrypted data goes here>

  pre_tasks:
    - block:
        - name: verify we can decode vault
          debug:
            var: test_var
          no_log: true
          run_once: true
      rescue:
        - name: fail playbook if decode failed
          fail:
            msg: You did not provide a vault pass or it is not recognized
  tasks:
    - name: a task
      debug:
        msg: I'll be played if pre_tasks are ok
```

Would this make the trick in your situation ?